# Android Pen Testing

Tags: android

I have been pen testing a random android app that uses POST method to send data to a remote server using HTTPS.

I have set up a proxy and am able to intercept the traffic, however the POST method appears to be encrypted and "url-encoded" .

What i want to know is .. is there a common encryption standard followed in such a scenario something like the Base64 or would it be so that the application uses a signature encryption mechanism internally which encrypts the data before it is sent through the POST method.

Any guidance would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: I believe this question is off topic here as the question is more about pen testing and POST method than Android.

Comment: You probably should send it through an SSL connection? Anyways, it's off topic here, developing questions belong on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can set encoding to whatever you like

```
UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameAndValuePairsGoHere,"encoding goes here");
```

Full example, credit: [Source](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```